# BaseTen Framework newbie question

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I am a newbie in Cocoa and, while waiting for my copy of Aaron Hillegas book, I thought I'd give BaseTen framework a try. I am currently following the tutorial provided online but have struck a problem.

In the tutorial I'm supposed to be able to enter the URI/connection string as an attribute of the BXDatabaseContext object. Well, the Attribute Inspector section for that object is blank. I can't find anywhere I can enter this.

Has anyone tried this with the latest version of the framework?

Many thanks,
Dany.

Comment: Not the answer you want, but if you're just learning Cocoa, starting with BaseTen, which is an API-level port of Core Data for PostgreSQL is going to be painful. Apple's docs list Core Data as an "advanced" Cococa framework. Grokking Core Data depends on grokking many Cocoa idioms and patterns. BaseTen is yet one more layer. My advice: wait for the Hillegas book and work through it. Then start on Core Data/BaseTen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Barry, yeah, I figured it's a step deeper to dwell into BaseTen but I'm the fidgety impatient sort :o) It wasn't too difficult to grok the basics of binding and such, even lead me to implementing a value converter (or is it transformer?) when I got the warning that "data" binding for NSImageView is being deprecated. It's has quite a few similarities to the WPF world I live in, although that's somewhat a broad generalisation to good/bad effects depending how you look at it. Then again, it's all a little superficial. Now I've struck another problem which probably requires me to have deeper knowledge of a Cocoa app life cycle. So...back to waiting for the Hillegas book and perhaps responses from the BaseTen mailinglist.

In the meantime, my original issue turned out to be a 32 vs 64 bit running of XCode and IB. I set both to run in 32bit mode and voila! All the various attributes appear as they should!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the BaseTen IBPlugin installed? (I'm assuming there is one.)